# Whats wrong with my code. I want to add new item in the cart with the existing item

Tags: php

Whats wrong with my code. I want to add new item in the cart with the existing item

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item'])
 {
 $dish[0]= array('meal_type'=>$meal_type,'meal_package'=>$meal_package,'meal_time'=>$meal_time,'meal_plan_days'=>$meal_plan_days,'meal_dish_type'=>$meal_dish_type,'prefixed_qty'=>$prefixed_qty,'prefixed_date'=>$prefixed_date,'cart_plan'=>$cart_total,'product_rule'=>$product_rule);


    $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item'] = $dish;
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['cart_total'] =  $cart_total*$prefixed_qty;

    }
    else
    {
        $item[]=array('meal_type'=>$meal_type,'meal_package'=>$meal_package,'meal_time'=>$meal_time,'meal_plan_days'=>$meal_plan_days,'meal_dish_type'=>$meal_dish_type,'prefixed_qty'=>$prefixed_qty,'prefixed_date'=>$prefixed_date,'cart_plan'=>$cart_total,'product_rule'=>$product_rule);

        $dish=array_push($dish,$item);

        $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item'] = $dish;
    $_SESSION['shopping_cart']['cart_total'] =  $cart_total*$prefixed_qty;

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What goes wrong, what platform do you use, do you get an error message, there is not enough information to anwser your question.

Comment: i want to add new item to cart. but not getting that new item in cart with the already existing one. am using php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$item[] = array(
                'meal_type' => $meal_type,
                'meal_package' => $meal_package,
                'meal_time' => $meal_time,
                'meal_plan_days' => $meal_plan_days,
                'meal_dish_type' => $meal_dish_type,
                'prefixed_qty' => $prefixed_qty,
                'prefixed_date' => $prefixed_date,
                'cart_plan' => $cart_total,
                'product_rule' => $product_rule
                );

$_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item'] = array_merge($_SESSION['shopping_cart']['item'], $item);
```